# Hide table row based on table cell pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an form which add the input to an HTML table. I want to do a dropdown where the user can filter for specific table cell elements only in pure Javascript and a filter method.

Let's say I have an table like this:

| Name | Age | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | 14 | 3 |
| Herb | 34 | 4 |
| John | 14 | 6 |

And a dropdown like this:

Select Name:
Anna
Herb
John

In the case the user selects Anna only the following table should showed:

| Name | Age | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | 14 | 3 |

The tricky part is that every row is created through the input from an form what means that I can't talk to an specific table row per id or class.

Here is what I tried:

For the Javascript part I tried to get all the elements from the table cell which should contain the value from the select button and if this element is != the value from the select button I hide the table row. I don't know how to get the table row through a table cell element.

```js
function changeDisplayTable() {
  //here i get all the values from the table cell departments in an array as text
  var dataCellsDepartments = document.getElementsByClassName(" dep"); //if does not work try " dep"
  var listWithTextContentDepartments = [];
  var i = 0;
  len = dataCellsDepartments.length;
  while (i < len) {
    listWithTextContentDepartments.push(dataCellsDepartments[i].textContent)
    i++
  }
  console.log(listWithTextContentDepartments);
  //array filtern und dann durch jede row gehen und checken if row contains one of the elem from array
  const result = listWithTextContentDepartments.filter(checkDepartment);

  function checkDepartment(department) {
    return department
  }

  //wenn selected elem != elem from table row --> hide table row

}
```

```html
<table id="table" class="tableZebra" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Student_Id</th>
    <th>First_Name</th>
    <th>Last_Name</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Department</th>
    <th>Email_Id</th>
    <th>Joining Date</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<form>
  <p>*Staff_Id:</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="Staff_Id" placeholder="Staff_Id"></div>
  <p>*First_Name:</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="First_Name_staff" placeholder="First_Name"></div>
  <p>Last_Name:</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="Last_Name_staff" placeholder="Last_Name"></div>
  <p>DOB:</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="DOB_staff" placeholder="DOB"></div>
  <p>Gender:</p>
  <div><input type="radio" id="GenderFemale_staff" placeholder="Gender" name="test"></div>
  <label for="html">Female</label>
  <div><input type="radio" id="GenderMale_staff" placeholder="Gender" name="test"></div>
  <label for="html">Male</label>
  <p>*Email_Id:</p>
  <div><input type="text" id="Email_Id_staff" placeholder="Email_Id"></div>
  <div class="distance-submit"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="onClickCheckFormStaff()"></div>
  <div class="error-staff" id="error-staff">*Fill out all mandatory fields</div>
</form>
<p>*Department:</p>
<select name="departments" id="Departments">
  <option value="empty">------</option>
  <option value="Department_1">Department_1</option>
  <option value="Department_2">Department_2</option>
  <option value="Department_3">Department_3</option>
  <option value="Department_4">Department_4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please click [edit] then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML and REMOVE IRRELEVANT code to make a [mcve] - you are missing `onClickCheckFormStaff `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you want to filter based on department and you're trying to display the data based on the selected department.

Here what you need to do is keep your data stored in a variable and render the table based on another variable which changes when the filter information is selected.

If you're going for a simple approach then use a file(json, csv, text, xlsx) of you choice. Write a function to read the file and save the info in "var data". Everytime while submitting a form, add it to your file by writing another write function. Also, call the read function after the write is done so that "var data" has the updated data with the newly added information

If you're using csv file the jQuery-CSV library has a function called $.csv.toObjects(csv) that does the mapping automatically.

File is save in the below format
heading1,heading2,heading3,heading4,heading5
value1_1,value2_1,value3_1,value4_1,value5_1
value1_2,value2_2,value3_2,value4_2,value5_2

To read the file use this
var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv):

The output would look like the data below in the "var data"
For example:-

```
var data = [
   {Student_Id : 123
    First_Name: John
    Last_Name: doe
    ...
    Department: ABC
    ...}
    {Student_Id :3456
    First_Name:Jane 
    Last_Name: Doe
    .....
    Department:DEF
    ....}
]
```

Use another variable for populating the table data say "studentTableData"

Now in default condition when no filter is applied do

```
var studentTableData = data
```

When a filter is selected instead of hiding the table rows,filter the data of "studentTableData" based on the selected department and render the table again(in simpler words replace the table)

```
var department_selected = "ABC"

var studentTableData = data.filter(function(el){
return el.Department == department_selected 
})
//var studentTableData will now have an array of data where department name matches the selected name
```

Comment: I just ask me how I can bring my form input in your "var data" style.

Comment: If you're using a DB then you can fetch the data from DB using an API. Call the API to get the data.
If you're going for a more simple approach then use a file(json, csv, text, xlsx) of you choice. Write a function to read the file and save the info in "var data". Also everytime you add something in the form and submit add it to your file by writing another write function to the file. Also, call the read function after the write is done so that "var data" has the updated data with the newly added information

Comment: If you use a csv file then the jQuery-CSV library has a function called $.csv.toObjects(csv) that does the mapping automatically

var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv):

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table row from a cell using [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) :

```
var tableRow = tableCell.closest("tr");
```

Note that this method [is not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#browser_compatibility) on internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

more simple with [.cells[ x ]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) row property

sample code:

```js
const
  data = 
    [ { name: 'Anna', age:14, id: '6' }
    , { name: 'Herb', age:34, id: '4' }
    , { name: 'John', age:14, id: '6' }
    ]
, theSelect = document.querySelector('#my-select')
, tableBody = document.querySelector('#my-table tbody')
, myForm    = document.querySelector('#my-form')
  ;
  
theSelect.onchange = e =>  // ********** here it is ! **********
  {
  if (theSelect.value==='*')
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr=>tr.className = '')
  else
    tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr=>
      {
      tr.classList.toggle('noDisplay', tr.cells[0].textContent!==theSelect.value )
      })
  }
  
// just  adding code for testing...
function addRow(obj)
  {
  let nRow = tableBody.insertRow()
  nRow.insertCell().textContent = obj.name
  nRow.insertCell().textContent = obj.age
  nRow.insertCell().textContent = obj.id

  theSelect.add( new Option(obj.name,obj.name))
  }
data.forEach(addRow)

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  addRow( Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries()))
  e.preventDefault()
  myForm.reset()
  theSelect.selectedIndex = 0
  tableBody.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr=>tr.className='')
  }
```

```css
html {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  }
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color: #9bbad8;
}
form {
  padding     :  0 3em;
  }
label { 
  line-height : 2em;
  }
input {
  display       : block;
  margin-bottom : .6em;
  }
button { 
  margin-top : 1em;
  width      : 5em;
  }
.noDisplay {   /* display or not display, this is your question...*/
  display : none;
}
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="" disabled selected> Please pick one...</option>
  <option value="*"> All </option>
</select>
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr><td>name</td><td>age</td><td>id</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<form id="my-form">
  <label >
    name
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" required>
  </label>
  <label >
    age
    <input type="number" name="age" value="" min="1" required>
  </label>
  <label >
    id
    <input type="text" name="id" value="" required>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
  <button type="reset">reset</button>
</form>
```